# What's the difference between a JRPG and a KRPG?

Tags: terminology

"J" should stand for Japan, while "K" should stand for "Korean"; I've met this term a few times and I'd like to know more about the differences on J/K (Computer) RPG.

Comment: Could you please post in a comment several (e.g. five) titles of non-MMO Korean RPGs? It is an interesting topic, as I haven't seen many of these published worldwide. Thanks!

Comment: Zenonia 1,2,3,4, Queen's Crown, Wild Frontier.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I am no expert but I believe the fundamental differences between the two subgenres are:

**KRPGS:**

- Lots of [grinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grinding_%28video_gaming%29)
- Technical character builds
- Item based
- Weaker story line

**JRPGs:**

- Strong storyline
- Less about specialised player builds
- Faster to 'progress' your character.

Comment: This is also how I percieve the differences in genre.

Comment: Just note quite a few first (NES/SNES-era) or old-school jRPGs were notorious of high difficulty, requiring significant grinding to level up characters.

Comment: @sarmackie - Yeah. Zelda II comes to mind.

Comment: @ire_and_curses I was thinking more along the lines of Final Fantasy and Dragon Warrior.

Comment: I know this is an old question and response, but I'd love to hear about some examples of KRPGs with technical character builds. Are we talking more about MMOs like Ragnarok Online or something else?